# PHPunit fails with "Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 5242880 bytes)" after upgrade to PHP 8.0.16

Tags: php, laravel, docker, memory-management, phpunit

In my Laravel project I upgraded to currently latest Laravel 9.3.0 and PHP 8.0.16.

The original version was Laravel 8.64 with PHP 7.4.

I run the project in Docker containers with `php:8.0.16-fpm-alpine` image. Previous was `php:7.4-fpm-alpine`.

This is my Docker container config in `docker-compose.yml` file:

```yaml
version: "3"
services:
  php:
    build:
      context: ./.docker-config/dockerfiles
      dockerfile: php.dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./laravel:/var/www/html:delegated
    networks:
      - mynetwork
```

And here is the `php.dockerfile`:

```
FROM php:8.0.16-fpm-alpine

WORKDIR /var/www/html

RUN apk add --no-cache --repository http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community/ --allow-untrusted gnu-libiconv
ENV LD_PRELOAD /usr/lib/preloadable_libiconv.so php

ENV PHP_MEMORY_LIMIT=2G
ENV PHP_UPLOAD_MAX_FILESIZE: 512M
ENV PHP_POST_MAX_SIZE: 512M

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql
# ...
```

As you see I set **2 GB** for PHP memory limit.

When I run `docker-compose run --rm phpunit` I get this error:

```
PHPUnit 9.5.16 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

...............................................................  63 / 281 ( 22%)
......................
   Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Error\FatalError

  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 5242880 bytes)

  at database/migrations/2022_01_21_120600_create_tags_table.php:16
     12▕      * @return void
     13▕      */
     14▕     public function up()
     15▕     {
  ➜  16▕         Schema::create('tags', function (Blueprint $table) {
     17▕             $table->id();
     18▕             $table->string('name')->default('');
     19▕             $table->string('type')->default('');
     20▕             $table->string('color', 7)->default('');
```

Here is the referred migration file. I think, nothing special:

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

return new class extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('tags', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name')->default('');
            $table->string('type')->default('');
            $table->string('color', 7)->default('');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->softDeletes();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('tags');
    }
};
```

Earlier same error happend on different migration file.

Any idea what's going on and how can I solve this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: The nasty thing about "out of memory" errors is that they often occur in spots that have little to do with the cause of the error itself. Common reasons are endless loops, or just trying to keep too much data in memory. You know how much data you're processing, and endless loops can be found by doing a stack dump before you run out of memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use in Dockerfile for solving memory limitation

```
RUN echo memory_limit = -1 >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-memlimit.ini;
```

Comment: This is a solution, but not the best one, since it means you are doing something wrong in your tests... @netdjw Are you using the trait `DatabaseRefresh` or any similar? or are you implementing your own stuff? What are you doing? Allowing "all memory" to be used is not a good solution, because it means you have a memory leak or anything similar that MUST BE fixed...

Answer (score 2):

For the record, I'm running into the same issue. Also after a Laravel 8->9 upgrade. And also specifically at various migrations.

I'll keep on searching for a solution, but since we both suffer the same issue in the same situation, it might be related to the Laravel 9 upgrade.

EDIT: It turns out php8 and/or php unit has a memory leak. The reason why this gave me real issues is that it turned out I had a manual memory override in my code somewhere:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '256M');
```

After removing this, my tests run without issues. Of course this isn't a solution for the memory leaks, but at least my tests are able to run.

If you have the same issues, check your code for similar mistakes.